# Java - ProcessBuilder Doesn't Pass -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize To The JVM

Tags: java, out-of-memory, processbuilder

I have a Java program which gets OutOfMemoryError due to lack of Direct Memory.
It can be easily fixed when I set the **-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize** to bigger memory size. It works fine from command line:

```
java -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=1024m -jar launcher1.4.5.jar
```

But when I run the same program with the same switches using **ProcessBuilder** I still get the same OutOfMemoryError even though I set the -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize switch.

```
List<String> command = new ArrayList<String>();
command.add("java");
command.add("-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=1024m");
command.add("-Xmx1024m");
command.add("-jar");
command.add("launcher1.4.5.jar");

ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
processBuilder.command(command);
File log = new File("log");
if(log.exists()) {
    log.delete();
}
processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
processBuilder.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.appendTo(log));
Process process = processBuilder.start();

StreamGobbler sg = new StreamGobbler(process.getInputStream(),System.out::println);
Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(sg);
int exitCode = process.waitFor();
System.out.printf("Program ended with exitCode %d", exitCode);
```

Now, if I pass the "java -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=1024m -jar launcher1.4.5.jar" to a **bat** file and run that bat file using the ProcessBuilder it will work just fine.
So the problem is ProcessBuilder not sending -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize switch to the JVM when running a jar file

Comment: How do you determine this?

Comment: I don't see the `java` command in your code

Comment: sorry fixed the sample code

Comment: That's better!!!

Comment: Although it seems unimportant, but still: What happens when you run ``java -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=1024m -Xmx1024m -jar launcher1.4.5.jar``? You only set ``-Xmx`` for the ``ProcessBuilder`` command but not for your other trials.

Comment: And how much free memory is available on that system? Is it tight (just barely enough free memory before staring the ``launcher1.4.5.jar``)?

Comment: @IvoMori It's a strong gaming computer with lots of free memory

Answer (score 1):

OK, So it looks like the root cause of this weird problem was due to the Java installation which seems to be for **32 bit**. Changed that to 64 bit and now everything works just fine.
I checked it using:

```
java -XshowSettings:properties -version
```